# How do I hang onto an izumi.reflect.Tag?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, izumi

I've been using `izumi.reflect.Tag` to hold onto type info, and it works great. Except when I lose that type info at some point, and then I'm not sure how to get it back. Here's what I want to do:

```
case class Rule[T: Tag](lhs: String, rhs: Repr[T])
```

This is great. A `Rule` knows the type of the `rhs` inside it. Except...

```
val rules: List[Rule[?]] = // some list of rules
rules.foreach { r =>
  process(r)
}

def process[T: Tag](rule: Rule[T]): Unit = // side-effectful processing
```

At this point, I get `could not find implicit value for izumi.reflect.Tag[T]`. OK, no big surprise. That `Tag` can't be recovered, because it got mixed in with all the other tags in the `List`. But is there some way I can save the tag to get it back later?

I've tried

```
case class Rule[T: Tag](lhs: String, rhs: Repr[T]):
   val LightTypeTag = Tag[T].tag
```

and similar ways of holding onto the `Tag` so that I could do something like

```
process(r, r.tag)

def process[T: Tag](rule: Rule[T], tag: Tag[T]) = ...
```

or explicitly passing a `Tag[T]` into the `process` method, but I can't figure out how to do any of the following:

1. Save a value of type `Tag[T]`.
2. Convert a value of type `LightTypeTag` back to a `Tag[T]`.
3. Some other combination of explicit saving and using some other values that will make this type check.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Of course, after I posted this, I think I got an answer, but I'd like to be sure it's the right one. I realized I really wanted a `Tag[T]` and I couldn't figure out how to get one, but then I realized that I had a `given Tag[T]` available, so I did

```
case class Rule[T: Tag](lhs: String, rhs: Repr[T]):
  val tag: Tag[T] = summon[Tag[T]]
```

and if I add `(using rule.tag)` in the places where I'm missing the implicit `Tag[T]`, things seem to work. Is this the right way to handle this?

Comment: I'd say implicit in a case class is an anti-pattern, there would be no problem if you defined `Rule` as `case class Rule[T](lhs: String, rhs: Repr[T], tag: Tag[T])` and then created a factory method in a companion object that takes an implicit argument.